# Populate ComboBox with Each FileType From Directory

Tags: vb.net, list, combobox

Basically, I have a `ComboBox` which I want to populate with `File Extensions` from a specific `Directory`.

Currently, I'm using:

```
Dim dir = "C:\"
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
   cmb_FileTypes.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file))
Next
```

This doesn't work properly because it basically loads all the extensions for all the files in the directory. I want it so that it shows each ONE file type. for instance, if there are 10 files:

- File1.jpg
- File2.jpg
- File3.png
- File4.mp3
- File5.mp3
- File6.dat
- File7.dat
- File8.tif
- File9.jpg
- File10.mp3

Out of these 10 Files, there are 6 file extensions that are different file extensions:

- Jpg
- Png
- Mp3
- Dat
- tif

How do I load each 1 one these file extensions into the ComboBox rather than just repeating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to group the extensions

```
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(dir).[Select](Function(p) Path.GetExtension(p)).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(p) p).ToList()
    cmb_FileTypes.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file))
Next
```

or you can create a method which returns a `List<string>` containing unique extensions.

```
Public Function UniqueExtensions(filenames As String()) As List(Of String)
    Dim extSet As New HashSet(Of String)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    For Each file As String In filenames
        extSet.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file))
    Next
    Return extSet.ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: Can't get it to work because 'List' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of String)'. Why does it say that?

Comment: Try `ToList()` instead. Sorry, I don't use VB.NET much so it's a translation from `C#`

Answer (score 2):

Use `LINQ` to add all the extensions to the combobox in one bulk.

```
cmb_FileTypes.Items.AddRange((From name In Directory.GetFiles(dir) Select Path.GetExtension(name).Replace(".", "") Distinct).ToArray())
```

Comment: Thanks for your input buddy but keyboardP used LINQ and got it to work!

Comment: Sorry for not being the *first* to post, but it takes some time to test the code before posting it. Btw, `AddRange` is the preferred way to add multiple items and I bet you don't want the periods to be included in the list of ext.

Comment: Yes you're right and your code works too! If you were first I woulda given it but I will find use for yours too. Just remember you've helped me too!